# Como criar um JOB no Oracle?

Tags: oracle, índices, job

Tenho o comando abaixo para realizar a análise dos índices do Oracle:

```sql
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS('USUARIO', estimate_percent=> 25);
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para agendar este comando para que ele rode 1 vez a cada semana.

**Editado:** Versão do Oracle: 11g.

Comment: Essa pergunta se aplica ao `Oracle Scheduler` certo? Poderia também dizer qual é versão do Oracle? 11g?

Comment: Agora você plantou mais uma dúvida.. Devo usar o JOB ou o SCHEDULER para este caso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A documentação do Oracle 11g diz o seguinte com respeito aos [Jobs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#ADMIN12382):

> Um Job é uma combinação de um horário agendado e um programa, juntamente com os argumentos adicionais exigidos pelo programa.

O exemplo de criação de um Job (usando ainda a documentação) é:

```sql
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'update_sales',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY',
   start_date         =>  '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
   end_date           =>  '20-NOV-08 07.00.00 PM Australia/Sydney',
   job_class          =>  'batch_update_jobs',
   comments           =>  'My new job');
END;
/
```

No exemplo, a procedure `OPS.SALES_PKG.UPDATE_SALES_SUMMARY` será executada a cada dois dias, a partir de 28 de Abril até 20 de novembro de 2008. Não tem muito segredo, é só entender os parâmetros. No seu caso você provavelmente vai querer usar a frequência `WEEKLY`.

Sobre [`Schedules`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse004.htm#ADMIN12412), a documentação diz o seguinte:

> Um Schedule define quando um Job deve executar ou quando uma janela deve abrir. Schedules podem ser compartilhadas entre usuários ao serem criadas e salvas no banco de dados.

Basicamente um Schedule permite usar um Job existente, mas a funcionalidade é muito parecida. Exemplo:

```sql
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
  schedule_name     => 'my_stats_schedule',
  start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  end_date          => SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '30' day,
  repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=HOURLY; INTERVAL=4',
  comments          => 'Every 4 hours');
END;
/
```

[Este link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#ADMIN12070) tem diversos exemplos para todos os gostos.