# Análise de tabela com Log de execução

Tags: sql, oracle

Possuo uma tabela no Oracle 11g com a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE USER.LOG_EXECUCAO
(
  ID                       NUMBER,
  DATA                     DATE,
  QTD_REGISTROS_INSERIDOS  NUMBER,
  TEMPO_EXECUCAO           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)
```

Um exemplo de dados:

```
ID      DATA                QTD_REGISTROS_INSERIDOS TEMPO_EXECUCAO

6356    04/04/2016 09:36:03 1074    00h:00m:58s:769ms
6355    04/04/2016 09:33:00 1074    00h:00m:56s:221ms
6354    04/04/2016 09:30:11 1074    00h:01m:06s:719ms
6353    04/04/2016 09:27:13 1074    00h:01m:08s:977ms
6352    04/04/2016 09:24:13 1074    00h:01m:09s:361ms
6351    04/04/2016 09:21:12 1074    00h:01m:07s:685ms
6350    04/04/2016 09:18:11 1074    00h:01m:06s:657ms
6349    04/04/2016 09:15:01 1074    00h:00m:57s:074ms
```

Essa tabela é alimentada por um executável C#, que roda de 3 em 3 minutos.. Porém pode acontecer do executável parar de rodar por indisponibilidade do servidor... e eu preciso saber quando foi essa parada.. Confesso que não consegui pensar em nada para poder resolver esse problema... alguém tem alguma ideia que possa me retornar algo do tipo:

> Entre a data X e Y, houve uma falha na execução durante X minutos. (difereça de uma data para outra)

A ideia era tentar resolver por SQL.... Sugestões?

Comment: O Oracle não tem Jobs para fazer isso?

Comment: Desconheço, amigo.... não sei te dizer

Comment: [Veja isso aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122/como-criar-um-job-no-oracle)

Comment: acredito que seja muito mais melhor você mante sua logica toda no banco se os seus dados já vinharem de lá. (Essa tabela é alimentada por um executável C#)

Comment: Ah, sim... o job em si eu conheço, porém é inviável... o executável C# faz coisas que através de PL/SQL eu não consigo fazer, tipo acessar determinados sites, monitorar se um servidor está fora ou não - através de ping.

Comment: @MarllonNasser você poderia usar procedure?

Comment: @MarlonTiedt, gostaria que a informação viesse em tempo real...nada que a procedure também não faça, eu pegando uma lógica pra fazer o select, posso trabalhar em cima disso, entende?

Comment: @MarllonNasser coloca o seu script com dados no http://sqlfiddle.com/ com dados ok e dados não ok, que vou tentar te ajudar

Comment: obrigado, @MarlonTiedt! Consegui uma resposta e coloquei à disposição para quem quiser fazer algo parecido :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pergunta respondida no [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403156/analyze-log-table-oracle-11g/36403493#36403493), existe uma função do oracle que mostra o registro anterior, a função [LAG e LEAD](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions)***(em inglês)***, então a ideia é, para cada registro, pegar a data do registro anterior, fazer a diferença entre eles e trazer somente os registros que possuem diferença maior que X minutos:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID, DATA, LAG (DATA) OVER (ORDER BY DATA) AS data_anterior,
               LEAD (DATA) OVER (ORDER BY DATA) AS data_posterior,
               FLOOR ((DATA - LAG (DATA) OVER (ORDER BY DATA)) * 24 * 60
                     ) AS minutos_diferenca
          FROM LOG_EXECUCAO)
 WHERE minutos_diferenca > 10
```

No exemplo acima, obtendo sempre a data do registro anterior e posterior, e "pego" a diferença em minutos sempre de acordo com o registro anterior..

Resultado obtido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]